# In a binary numpy array, how to change a row to value True , If all elements of that row is False?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array as follows

```
DeviceArray([[ True, False,  True],
             [False, False, False],
             [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

As we can see the second row is all false, since all of the elements of the second row is false we want to transform all of it to True such as

```
DeviceArray([[ True, False,  True],
             [True, True, True],
             [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

> I can do this with for loop, but I am looking something which will be efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) on row axis and reverse the mask:

```
a = np.array([[ True, False,  True],
             [False, False, False],
             [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

a[~a.any(axis=1)] = True
```

Output:

```
>>> a
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

Details:

```
>>> a.any(axis=1)
array([ True, False,  True])  # which rows contain at least 1 True

>>> ~a.any(axis=1)
array([False,  True, False])  # so which rows have only False

>>> a[~a.any(axis=1)]
array([[False, False, False]])  # second row of your array
```